# Convert a tuple of types to an intersection

Tags: typescript

How can one convert a tuple of types into an intersection of all of those types at once?

```js
type TupleToIntersection<
  Rest extends any[],
  T = Rest extends [any, ...any[]] ? Rest['0'] : never,
> = Rest extends [infer H, ...infer S] ? TupleToIntersection<S, H & T> : T


type TTest1 = TupleToIntersection<[string,any,number]> // any but should be never!

type Test1 = string & any & number   // never
type Test2 = (string & any) & number // any - what TupleToIntersection is doing
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCMUC8VECcCWA7A5lAGRQCGuIxUuArgLYBGEmUrUA9O9RAG7MBQoSLATAATGigAKLHkIlyIAJRVajZq05kK-XUOgwaYADYQYAewCSuYM3gQAxsGzncAHn6sASqKgQAHra4ACbw2iAA2gC6ADSesJI+iH6BECFhEYoxUAB0eYrRUVAA-FBJwBEA5AAMlUUAXNx8mHEAfIm+AUGhUBF4AGYaABLZeTkDGgDKRaWGJmZWNnaOzq5uk9lDVDDtjTC6guAGcIgo6HOmFta2mPZOLu4RsgQxWWpMmFHtWopQDDTADAAC3MNGMwT+0FwvGYAEIgA)

Comment: This is a *strange* question. I usually define `TupleToIntersection` [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/w1n1kN), and that gives you the `never` you want, but if TS's `&` operation isn't perfectly associative then there's nothing *incorrect* about your version of `TupleToIntersection`, it just gives a different answer from what you were expecting due to the way intersections work. Can you elaborate? Maybe reword the question to be like "how can I compute an intersection on tuple elements *all at once* instead of accumulating them recursively?" and not imply that your version is doing something wrong?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you very much.  Yes that's the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `TupleToIntersection` as follows gives you what you're looking for:

```js
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void
} extends {
  [K: number]: (x: infer I) => void
}
  ? I
  : never
```

```js
type TTest1 = TupleToIntersection<[string,any,number]> // never
type TTest2 = TupleToIntersection<['a' | 'b', 'b' | 'c']> // b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler and also can be use with more than two elements:

```
type ListToIntersection<R extends any[]> = R extends [infer H, ...infer S] ? H & ListToIntersection<S>  : unknown.
```

Comment: thanks, yes that's simpler than the way I did it in the question.  However, it also does not return never for `[string, any, number]`, but rather returns `any`.